# android: does ScrollView has different default backgrounds for different API level?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with some children inside.

For API 23, the `ScrollView` has a white background. But for API 22 and below, the background is gray. I didn't set background in xml or code. All remaining default. Activity and fragment also have default background in layout xml. Activity theme is Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar by default, and Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar for v21.

I saw this on:

> samsung note 5 with 6.0.0: white
>
> android emulator Nexus 6P with 6.0.0: white
>
> samsung s6 with 5.1.1: gray
>
> android emulator Nexus 6P with 5.1.1: gray
>
> Xiaomi 4 LTE with 4.4.4: gray
>
> android emulator Nexus 6P with 4.4.4: gray

based on the above test, I guess the background related to API levels.

If I set background to white in xml, for API 22 and below, I can see white background.

Any ideas?

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: I think its nothing to do with some API level. Its somewhat device specific I guess. Never really faced the problem as I always set a proper background color. Which is also recommended to do so I guess.

Comment: i would bet the `ScrollView` is transparent in all API levels, isn't what you see the parent's background?

Comment: @pskink all activity and fragment have not set background, all remaing default.

Comment: so its the root window that has a background, not your `ScrollView`, its most likely `android:windowBackground` but i'm nit 100% sure though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't provided an explicit color, it might take the color from the default theme of the device. It doesn't depend on the API level, but the device theme.
Therefore, its also possible that you might see different colors for the same API level on two different devices.
Hence, if you want to be consistent across all devices, its always recommended to set the color you want explicitly.

Comment: yes! set value explicitly for what I want. thx. but i wonder why the color changes across API levels, please refer to my post for tested devices.

Comment: Because each API level comes with a specific theme, e.g holo.light or holo.dark, etc. Depending upon the theme for that API, the color changes. Same goes across different devices. If you want to make your component color theme independent, you must use explicit color.

Comment: seems to be reasonable. but i dont really think themes could differ so much for the simple background...

Comment: Themes don't differ for the background, but the device in general. So, default colors for one theme may not be the same for the default colors for another theme. Hence we may see different background colors, or any other component's color that is left to be of the default color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your styles for the same background in different android API:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
```